# Current Loops VS Permanent Magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electric-current, magnetic-moment

I'm having a hard time understanding the big connection between permanent magnets and current loops. I am aware that they both have the *same magnetic field* and therefore it can be said that a current loop is a *magnet*. Also, I believe that they both exert *magnetic forces*. What are the key differences between current loops and permanent magnets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do we mean with magnetic monopole and dipole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173818/)

Comment: I think your question is too broad, this q&a format doesn't really matches long discussions. I suggest to edit it to ask to a more specific direction.

Comment: @YashasSamaga I don't see monopoles would be here mentioned.

Comment: @peterh That question's title is vague. It asks many questions and the question which the OP asked in that question is asked here.

Answer (score 1):

basically both current loops and permanent magnets work and behave due to one single reason, it's the current loop that's always there , permanent magnets work because electrons are whirling around nucleus add thus behave as tiny magnets. In a permanent magnet electrons are whirling around the nucleus and generate magnetic fields, in some substances like iron the magnetic fields generated due to billions of electrons add up and generate a net magnetic field, that's why it's always magnetic. So. Inclusion is this : what's actually existing is the current loop, it further gives rise to magnetism. Hope that helps.