# Why do magnetic fields exist as line?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, visualization

why there are no magnetic field lines between two magnetic field lines. why don't magnetic fields exist as a solid Ovid of influence?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251612/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

They do not exist as lines. The *shape* of the field follows the *curvature* of those lines, which are used to visualize the field. Everywhere between two of those lines, there is another one inbetween them, and inbetween those, and those, etc. The field fills space in reality but we visualize it with only a few lines on paper.

Answer (score 3):

The magnetic and electric fields do indeed exist at every point in space.  At every point $(x,y,z)$, there is a vector that points in the direction a particle under the influence of the field will be pushed. If you draw a line connecting several arrows together, you get the field lines.  But you cannot draw the lines at infinite density, or it would just be a solid black sheet that doesn't illustrate anything. So field lines are drawn to show the general layout of the field. It is simply a visual aid.  You are meant to assume parallel lines fill in the spaces between.